# Filtering ethernet packets (ICMP, Bonjour) on a TAP interface on OSX

Tags: networking, multicast, packet, ethernet, tun

I'm writing a little tunneling app with layer 2 interfaces (TAP) as endpoints. In the course of testing this on OSX, I noticed I was getting all sorts of traffic I didn't expect on the tunnel, both when the tunnel was running on a single OSX machine, and when I tunneled between OSX and a Linux box. I'd like to filter this traffic out, and I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

The tunnel looks like this (note both endpoints can be on the same machine):

```
tap0 -> tunnel app -> UDP tunnel -> tunnel app -> tap1
```

The notable traffic is Bonjour packets on destination port 5353 and ICMP/IGMP. Multicast is enabled on the TAP interface. I'd like to block this sort of traffic. My thoughts on doing this:

1. Turn off multicast on the interface (doesn't work on OSX, see below)
2. Use `ebtables`
3. Parse the packets coming off the interface inside the tunnel app and ignore them there

Is there a better/easier way to do this?

I tried turning off multicast on the OSX interface (let's call it tap0) but I get an error.

```
$ ifconfig tap0 -multicast
ifconfig: -multicast: bad value
```

EDIT: After a bit more hunting around, it appears UNIX and BSD ifconfig have different options. Is there another way to block multicast/ICMP traffic on a given interface in OSX/BSD?

---

here's the ifconfig output...

OSX (with osxtuntap):

```
$ ifconfig tap1
tap1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 92:d9:e6:65:5a:8c 
    inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    open (pid 17121)
```

Linux:

```
$ ifconfig tunX
tunX      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4a:29:02:e6:b0:b9  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4829:2ff:fee6:b0b9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the built-in ipfw firewall in OSX. From the terminal, we could allow only tcp traffic on a virtual network interface called tap1:

```
sudo ipfw add 9000 allow tcp from any to any via tap1 # allow tcp
sudo ipfw add 9001 deny ip from any to any via tap1 # block all other incoming and outboung traffic
```

And we can also delete the rules if we don't need them:

```
sudo ipfw del 9000 9001
```

Alternatively, it is possible to just parse the ethernet frame and convert it from ascii into hex or decimal, and then decide what to do with it there. You can very easily detect TCP/UDP packets with the below (protocol=6 for tcp, and 17 for udp).

```
from binascii import hexlify
...
# given some ethernet frame string data
protocol = int(hexlify(frame[23:24]), 16)
src_port = int(hexlify(frame[34:36]), 16)
dst_port = int(hexlify(frame[36:38]), 16)
```

For arp packets, this won't work- the packet structure is a bit different.